# blockchain что и как

Tags: blockchain

Подскажите где и что почитать доходчиво, как эта радость работает? Только не общими словами, типа «Блокчейн — это журнал с фактами, реплицируемый на несколько компьютеров, объединенных в сеть равноправных узлов (P2P)». Интересует подробно, с технической точки зрения. Четко пока даже вопрос сформулировать не могу.

В общих чертах понятно, а дальше, куда ни ткни, одни вопросы. Начиная, хотя бы, *как* она реплицирается по *всем* нодам? Что будет если нода (много нод) выпали на время из сети, или, например, отрезало целый город от внешнего мира, но внутри города народ что-то делал — как потом это вольется в «общую цепочку»?

Это просто навксидку вопрос. Если кто сочтет возможным поотвечать ну кучу таких «шибко умных» вопросов — буду рад. Или подскажите, где об этом внятно написано. Благодарю.

Comment: здесь все написано для новичков: https://medium.com/blockchain-review/how-does-the-blockchain-work-for-dummies-explained-simply-9f94d386e093

Comment: Меня интересует с точки зрения программиста. С изучения чего начинать? Все что удалось найти, это общие фразы для публики..

Comment: может я тупой, но мне недостаточно объяснения представить блекчейн "like a magical Google spreadsheet in the cloud".
Вот я программист, вот я хочу разобраться как работает эта штуковина. Я не вижу в ней пока ни одного преимущества, хочу "пощупать" это встоими руками и либо подтвердить, либо опровергнуть свои представления об этой "революции"..  Лучший способ - сто-то написать самомум. Возможно я разучился пользоваться гуглом, но я не могу найти с чего начать.. Если очень грубо - где "hello world" на блокчейне?..

Comment: И вот какую бы статбю не читал, чезде все сводится к валютам. А без валют блокчейн не бывает? Пишут же что в нем можно хранить что угодно. Если например в нем будут храниться.. ну не знаю, мед.спарвки или та мдоверенности какие-то (вместо натариусов). Тоже нужны валюты?. Майнеры обязаны быть? (им обязательно необходимо что-то зарабатывать?).. и т.д. и т.п...

Answer (score 0):

Если вы говорите о блокчейне похожий на блокчейн биткоина, то при объединении различающихся цепочек блокчейна верной будет выбрана та которая длиннее, то есть на которую потрачены большие мощности для майнинга.

Comment: Отлично - а как гарантируется что она действительно верная? Скажем (пусть применительно к биткоину, хотя меня не он интересует), я перевел что-то васе пупкину, а на другом конце платены Джон перевер чтото  Максу, но их там, в 100 раз больше чем нас тут ,и у них цепочка выросла длинее.. Что же, с такой логикой получится, что я ничего Васе не перводил?

Comment: Вот, предположим, у нас сеть из трех узлов А, В и С.  Узел С выпадает из сети, скажем на день. За это день Узел А перевел узлу В некую сумму(ну или локумент, там, довернность выдал на чтото.. не суть).  Теперь у узлов А и В есть об этом записи. А потом узел А взял и удалил у себя эту запись. А теперь узел С поключился. Что произойдет?  Как у зел С будет синхронизовать данные? Какая версия данных (А или В) в итоге станет верной?

Comment: Да такая вероятность есть, но это может произойти либо если от интернета отделиться очень большая часть. А интернет построен так что это очень маловероятно.Во вторых если в вашей сети нет значительных майнинговых мощностей, тоу вас блоки будут формироваться не за стандарное время (10 мин для биткоина), а очень долго.

Comment: Так всеже, что конкретно произойдет то? Вопрос не о вероятности такого в реальности, впрос - что будет в даннйок онкретной ситуации.

Comment: На основании чего решается включать ли транзакцию в блок? На основании чего решается какой блок включать в цепочку? _Кто_ это решает и _чем_ руководсткется?

Comment: Данные блокчейна храняться у всех узлов. И всегда есть майнеры которые формируют блокчейн и у них есть актуальные данные иначе они не смогли бы оперативно майнить. Во вторых если А делает перевод на кошелек В, то он передает эту информацию по соседним узлам и она транслируется всем кто есть в сети. Когда майнеры находят новый блок они включают запись о переводе A на кошелек B. И тогда все знают что эта операция подтверждена.

Comment: Вот написано что у хэша должно буть в переди N нолей. Хорошо, два (три, четыре, сто) нод (почти) одновременно находят такой хэш - Чей блок будет принят? При этом в их блоках могут содержаться разные транзакции? _Как_ инфорамция о том что Вася что-то переда Феде попадет ко _всем_?  А зато время блок геренируется (10минут) Вася передал тоже самое уже Пете, и эта тарнзакция тоже уже гдето в бругой блок включается.. Да еще и в цепочку включится раньше...  Непонятно кдля меня много, ответов, кроме общих дифирамбов не нахожу.

Comment: "Данные блокчейна храняться у всех узлов. " - это видится слабо вероятным,  хотя бы по той же причине отсутвия интернета. И _как_ конкретно эта информация попадает ко _всем_? (возможно нужно еще в каких-тосмежных вопросах разобраться - натолкните куда посмотерть). "всегда есть майнеры...у них есть актуальные данные" - откуда они эти данные берут? Откуда уверенность что они актулаьные? Данные у _всех_ майнеров _всегда_ одни и теже?

Comment: "Так всеже, что конкретно произойдет то?" Получится так как вы и сказали. Но если вы будете отключены от общей сети то скорее всего произойдет то что вы сдаете перевод и он долго не будет подтверждаться, пока не дойдет до серьезных майнеров.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72993/discussion-between-coder675-and-alexander).